# concatenate JSON paginated response with python requests

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I want to concatenate the JSON response of WordPress API with Python's library requests. Here is my code:

```
import requests
results = []
pagination = 1
url = 'https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?after=2019-01-01T00:00:00&before=2019-02-01T00:00:00&per_page=5&page={}'.format(pagination)
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.json()
for i in data:
    results.append(i)
while r.status_code == 200:
    pagination += 1
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.json()
    for i in data:
        results.append(i)
    else:
        break
print(results)
```

I end up with the 1st page only.

Comment: Your `url` variable is static: you update the value of `pagination`, but you never regenerated the formatted `url` string, so you're always requesting the first page regardless of how many requests you make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding the value when formatting the URL initially, this is never updated again.

Probably easier to pass some of your [params as a dictionary to requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls) instead of on the URL, and have the pagination update on each iteration, for example:

```
import requests
results = []
pagination = 1
url = 'https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?after=2019-01-01T00:00:00&before=2019-02-01T00:00:00'
params = {'per_page': 5, 'page': pagination}
r = requests.get(url, params=params)
data = r.json()
for i in data:
    results.append(i)
while r.status_code == 200:
    pagination += 1
    params['page'] = pagination
    r = requests.get(url, params=params)
    data = r.json()
    for i in data:
        results.append(i)
    else:
        break
print(results)
```